# I need to show total employees under specific managers but dont know how to trim this down

Tags: sql

```
SELECT manager.ename AS "Mgr Name", ( Select COUNT(*) 
                                        FROM emp worker
                                        WHERE worker.mgr = manager.empno
                                        ) AS "Total Emp"
FROM emp worker, emp manager
WHERE worker.mgr = manager.empno;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d472i.png)

Comment: Do you have different levels of managers and workers? Also, you say "specific managers", but your query isn't filtering in any way the managers, so it would show all the managers.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

How about this? It joins on the same table to match all managers with employees and returns the number of direct reports:

```
  SELECT 
      m.ename AS [Mgr Name], 
      COUNT(DISTINCT e.empno) AS [Total Emp]
   FROM emp e
   JOIN emp m ON m.empno = e.mgr 
   GROUP BY m.ename;
```

Comment: this is nice and simple

Answer (score 1):

Use either a correlated subquery *or* `join` with `group by`:

```
SELECT m.ename AS "Mgr Name",
       ( Select COUNT(*) FROM emp e WHERE e.mgr = m.empno
       ) AS num_employees
FROM emp m;
```

Comment: Not `distinct m.ename as "mgr name"`?